# Function freez button after add to cart

Tags: javascript

I want to freez button after someone has added a product to cart. Now my code works good but not perfect. I can't add something to cart because my script freez button. I want to disable it after something was added to cart.

```
let fewSeconds = 5;
$('.btn').click(function(){
    // Ajax request
    let btn = $(this);
    btn.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function(){
        btn.prop('disabled', false);
    }, fewSeconds*1000);
});
```

HTML:

`<button data-button-action="add-to-cart" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj do koszyka</button>`

Add section

````
                        <form action="https://www.ezoolandia.pl/koszyk" class="cart-form-url" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="token" class="cart-form-token" value="5018573430092b3a6810d3b5c0ec836a">
                            <input type="hidden" value="2959" name="id_product">
                            <input type="hidden" class="input-group form-control" value="1" name="qty">
                            <button data-button-action="add-to-cart" id="add-to-cart" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj do koszyka</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>```
````

Comment: Please, add relevant html too. You can doing it by clicking on edit link underneath your question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: do you mean you want to disable the function when product is added to cart?

Comment: I want to disable button for 5 seconds after product is aded to cart. My shop freez when someone spam add to cart button.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed your prop to attr. Please check below the snippet. If that's what you wanted to achieve

Update 1: the answer remove disabled only when we receive the response

Update 2: Please try adding id and get the button

```js
$('#add-to-cart').click(function(){
   
    let btn = $(this);
    btn.attr('disabled', true);
    // Ajax request replace with yours
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => btn.attr('disabled', false))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="add-to-cart">Click</button>
```

Comment: Everything remained the same. Clicking on the button freezes the button for 5 seconds but does not add the product to the bookmark. The action that is under the button does not want to be performed, only the button is immediately deactivated.

Comment: Now its working fine but still action add to cart not work. I add Html code of this button. 
`<button data-button-action="add-to-cart" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj do koszyka</button>`

Comment: I add id to button but i have the same issue.
`<button data-button-action="add-to-cart" id="add-to-cart" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj do koszyka</button>`

`$('#add-to-cart').click(function(){

    let btn = $(this);
    btn.attr('disabled', true);
    // Ajax request replace with yours
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => btn.attr('disabled', false))
});
`

Comment: [link](https://youtu.be/9cBoDkYDE0Q) here is how its works from last update.